# Compatibility of Nvidia's Tesla K80 GPU on Sun Solaris Sunfire X4270

Tags: nvidia

I would like to fix Nvidia's Tesla K80 GPU on Sun Solaris server Sunfire X4270. If someone know how to check the compatibility, it would be great help !

Answer (score 3):

First step: comparing data sheets. The x4270 offers only PCIe 2 x 8 connectors, while the K80 needs x 16. Problem solved.